# Why is the maximum work done by a voltaic cell negative

Tags: electrochemistry

The maximum work done by a voltaic cell is given by -nFE. Why the negative sign?  From what I know, a battery does positive work on the load attached to it

Answer (score 2):

It is negative because it's the work done by the system on the surroundings. Here our system is taken as the cell.

Maximum work is also taken as the change in Gibbs free energy $(ΔG)$.

Comment: But the system (the cell) is doing positive work on the surrounding (the load)

Comment: Work done by the system should be positive, work done by the surroundings on the system should be negative. Does -nFE represent the work done **on** the battery?

Comment: @xasthor Are you sure work done by system is taken positive ;) Are you aware of different conventions ? https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/66088/why-do-chemistry-and-physics-have-different-sign-convention-in-thermodynamics